# Preparing a state given access to projector

Tags: quantum-state, measurement

Let's say I am given access to a magical box that lets me apply a projector $|\psi\rangle \langle\psi|$, where $|\psi\rangle$ is a quantum state. I do not know anything about $|\psi\rangle$: just that I am given this magical box. Can I prepare $|\psi\rangle$, in a polynomial amount of time, using it?

One way to do it is: start with any arbitrary efficiently preparable quantum state, apply the projector. If the outcome is $1$, you have $|\psi\rangle$ as your post-measurement state. If not, repeat. Is this intuition correct? A problem I see with it is, the arbitrary quantum state can be almost orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$. There is no way of knowing whether or not it would be beforehand, as we know nothing about $|\psi\rangle$. Hence, the probability of succeeding in successfully projecting onto $|\psi\rangle$ can be exponentially small, and it will take us an exponentially large time to prepare the state.

Also, is the opposite true? If we can efficiently prepare a state, can we efficiently project onto that state?

Comment: I feel like you already answered the first part of the question. A projection is inherently probabilistic. If the input is orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$, you'll just never find $|\psi\rangle$. The second question looks ill-posed to me. You can efficiently prepare a state how? From what input? If you implement a map $\Phi$ such that for some input $\rho$ you have $\Phi(\rho)=|\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi|$, that doesn't mean that $\rho$ is not orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$ in the first place, nor that there must be any kind of relation between $\rho$ and $|\psi\rangle$, if that's what you are asking

Comment: Apply the projector to a maximally mixed state, and you can give yourself some probability guarantees!